# Why do I get same results directly within same run in second time without run random function in it in Python?

Tags: python, random, graph-algorithm

I write a KargerMinCut function in which I have written a random function in Python, but I get the same result within the same run. If I restart the function, different results printed.

Here's the code

```
import random

with open('test.txt') as f:
    #kargerMinCut
    #a = [[int(x) for x in ln.split()] for ln in f]
    data_set = []
    for ln in f:
        line = ln.split()
        if line:
            a = [int(x) for x in line]
            data_set.append(a)

def choose_random_edge(data):
    a = random.randint(0,len(data)-1)
    b = random.randint(1,len(data[a])-1)
    return a,b

def compute_nodes(data):
    data_head = []
    for i in xrange(len(data)):
        data_head.append(data[i][0])
    return data_head

def find_index(data_head,data,u,v):
    index = data_head.index(data[u][v])
    return index

def replace(data_head,data,index,u):
    for i in data[index][1:]:
        index_index = data_head.index(i)
        for position,value in enumerate(data[index_index]):
            if value == data[index][0]:
                data[index_index][position] = data[u][0]
    return data

def merge(data):
    u,v = choose_random_edge(data)
    print u,v
    data_head = compute_nodes(data)
    index = find_index(data_head,data,u,v)
    data[u].extend(data[index][1:])
    #print data
    data = replace(data_head,data,index,u)
    #print data
    data[u][1:] = [x for x in data[u][1:] if x!=data[u][0]]
    #print data
    data.remove(data[index])
    #print data
    return data

def KargerMinCut(data):
        while len(data) >2:
            data = merge(data)
            #print data
        num = len(data[0][1:])
        print num

#KargerMinCut(data_set)
```

Here's test.txt

```
1 2 3 4 7

2 1 3 4

3 1 2 4

4 1 2 3 5

5 4 6 7 8

6 5 7 8

7 1 5 6 8

8 5 6 7
```

**Editted** 12-28-2016

I have modified my code in **merge** and **replace** by adding local copy of input data. I don't know whether I'm right or not.

Here's the code

```
def replace(data_head,data,index,u):
    data1 = data
    for i in data[index][1:]:
        index_index = data_head.index(i)
        for position,value in enumerate(data[index_index]):
            if value == data[index][0]:
                data1[index_index][position] = data[u][0]
    return data1

def merge(data1):
    data = data1
    u,v = choose_random_edge(data)
    #print u,v
    data_head = compute_nodes(data)
    index = find_index(data_head,data,u,v)
    data[u].extend(data[index][1:])
    #print data
    data2 = replace(data_head,data,index,u)
    #print data
    data2[u][1:] = [x for x in data2[u][1:] if x!=data2[u][0]]
    #print data
    data2.remove(data2[index])
    #print data
    return data2
```

But when I run `merge(data_set)` I find that I have changed the input again. Why and what should I do? Could anybody give me some clues?

[Here is the output of merge and data_set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFCZS.png)

**Editted by adding wanted output image**

Here's the image:
[wanted output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMXjE.png)

I want to loop calculate `KargerMinCut(data_set)` and pick the min value as a output.
As you can see, when I loop calculate `KargerMinCut(data_set)` I should get the different result instead of same results which is wrong. I know I have change the input data when I call `KargerMinCut(data_set)`, but I don't know how to fix it.
**Problem solved in 1/7/2017**
I use `import copy` at the top and `data = copy.deepcopy(data)` in the first line of `KargerMinCut()`. Adding `calc_num()` function.
Here's the output:

```
calc_number(data_set,20)
17
calc_number(data_set,2)
17

calc_number(data_set,15)
20
calc_number(data_set,15)
17
```

Here's the code:
    import random
    import copy

```
with open('kargerMinCut.txt') as f:
    #kargerMinCut
    #a = [[int(x) for x in ln.split()] for ln in f]
    data_set = []
    for ln in f:
        line = ln.split()
        if line:
            a = [int(x) for x in line]
            data_set.append(a)

def choose_random_edge(data):
    a = random.randint(0,len(data)-1)
    b = random.randint(1,len(data[a])-1)
    return a,b

def compute_nodes(data):
    data_head = []
    for i in xrange(len(data)):
        data_head.append(data[i][0])
    return data_head

def find_index(data_head,data,u,v):
    index = data_head.index(data[u][v])
    return index

def replace(data_head,data,index,u):
    for i in data[index][1:]:
        index_index = data_head.index(i)
        for position,value in enumerate(data[index_index]):
            if value == data[index][0]:
                data[index_index][position] = data[u][0]
    return data

def merge(data):
    u,v = choose_random_edge(data)
    #print u,v
    data_head = compute_nodes(data)
    index = find_index(data_head,data,u,v)
    data[u].extend(data[index][1:])
    #print data
    data = replace(data_head,data,index,u)
    #print data
    data[u][1:] = [x for x in data[u][1:] if x!=data[u][0]]
    #print data
    data.remove(data[index])
    #print data
    return data

def KargerMinCut(data):

    data = copy.deepcopy(data)
    while len(data) >2:
        data = merge(data)
        #print data
    num = len(data[0][1:])
    return num

#KargerMinCut(data_set)
def calc_number(data,iteration):
    list = []
    for i in xrange(iteration):
        list.append(KargerMinCut(data))
    return min(list)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data_set` is a list and lists are mutable. If you follow the function calls: `KargerMinCut` calls `merge` and `merge` calls `replace`. Both `merge` and `replace` mutates the passed list.

`merge` mutates it in the line

```
data[u].extend(data[index][1:])
```

`replace` mutates it in the line

```
data[index_index][position] = data[u][0]
```

In a single session, the first time you call `KargerMinCut(data_set)` it mutates `data_set`, changing the input to the second call `KargerMinCut(data_set)`. That is why the two function calls behave differently.

If this isn't desirable, you could should start each function `merge` and `replace` by creating a local copy of `data`.

Comment: Mr.Coleman, It's very kind of you to help me. I appreciate it for your effort in my question. But I don't quite understand what you say. I have modified my 'merge' and 'replace' function and there're still some mistakes in my output.

Comment: @SSQ As I said in a deleted comment (since you can't edit comments after a few minutes) the problem with `data = data1` is that it creates an alias for the same list rather than a copy. You need to create *copies* and the `copy` module is a good way to do so. You could move the needed copying to the top level. Leave `merge` and `replace` alone but as the first line in `KargerMinCut` have the line `data = copy.deepcopy(data)`. This will prevent any changes from being made to the argument `data` (although of course other bugs might come to the surface).

Answer (score 0):

```
def KargerMinCut(data):
while len(data) > 2:  #here is the problem
    data = merge(data)
    # print data
num = len(data[0][1:])
print num
```

The problem is in the 2nd line.

in the 2nd call to KargerMinCut len(data)>2 so it just print the same num again.

Comment: Thank you Pio, I find that I have changed the input data, but I don't want to change the input data, what should I do? Could you please help me?

Comment: what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: I find out the where the problem is, thank you Pio !